# compile error in generate statement instantiating a component

Tags: vhdl

When I try to simulate a program using the generate statement calling a component it gives an error saying to check previous errors. this is when I use the "gen: for i in 0 to n-1 generate". but when I change it to "gen: for i in n-1 to 0 generate" it will let me simulate it but when I try to use the component, a 'Full_adder', the output does not output the answer, it just stays 'UUUU'. Any ideas? Code is below.

```
entity comtest is
generic (n : positive := 16);
     Port (
         abus, bbus: in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
         sbus: out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
         cai: in std_logic;
         cao: out std_logic);

end comtest;

architecture Behavioral of comtest is

  component Full_adder is
      generic(tpd: delay_length := 10ns);
      port (a, b, ci: in std_logic;
                s, co: out std_logic);
  end component;

  signal c: std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);



   begin
  gen: for i in 0 to n-1 generate
   --  gen: for i in n-1 to 0 generate
         fa: Full_adder port map (a => abus(i), b => bbus(i),ci =>     c(i-1), s => sbus(i), co => c(i));
  end generate;
  c(0) <= cai;
  cao <= c(n-1);


  end Behavioral;
```

Its probably something stupid but can get it to work. The full adder that I wrote works and the ports for it are declared correctly.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] along with the actual error message. The original error is due to i -1 as an index when i=0, it's out of bounds. The 'U's come from sbus not being driven when i has a null range (the commented gen should be downto you get no full_adder instantiations). (`10ns` should be `10 ns` even if Modelsim doesn't require it. IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal.")

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names "It is an error if an index value does not belong to the range of the corresponding index range of the array." Declare c (n downto 0). `for i in 0 to n - 1 generate` ...  `ci => c(i),` `co => c(i + 1)` and `cao <= c(n);`. These types of mistakes are sometimes called 'thinko's meaning incompletely thought out, much kinder than your own appellation.

Comment: thanks guys. got it sorted. the generate statement and the adder is working perfectly. i'm trying to put it in a case statement now but its not working. I can comment out the generate statement and the case statement works but when I put it back in it gives a syntax error. I knew the cao and the co => c(I + 1) was not accurate but I was just trying to get the thing simulated on some level before adjusting these. Any idea on the case statements and the syntax error with them?